# When considering matrices (or differential operators), $A > B \implies \exp(A) > \exp (B)$?

Tags: inequality, matrix-calculus, differential-operators

First, I would like to ask what is the conventionnal definition of $ A > B $ for matrices (or differential operators in my case of interest).

I guess that a natural definition would be that $A-B$ should be positive definite.
$$ A > B \iff A - B >0 \iff \langle \psi | (A - B) | \psi \rangle > 0 \ \ \forall \ |\psi \rangle$$
But if there are any equivalent definition, I would be happy to hear.

My question is, from this definition (or an equivalent one), is it true that
$$ A > B \implies \exp(A)  > \exp (B) $$
and if so, how to prove it ?

Comment: You want that for $|\psi\rangle \ne 0$.  $\langle 0 | (A-B) | 0 \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

$$ A =  \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{0.99 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$

Comment: Yes, thanks (edited)